# Query ReactiveMongo by a nested field

Tags: mongodb, scala, bson, reactivemongo

I have an object in a collection:

```
{ "id" : "123", "option" : { "key" : "one" , "value" : "1" }}
```

I can find the object like this:

```
collection.find(BSONDocument("option" -> BSONDocument("key" -> "one", "value" -> "1")))
```

However, what I need is to be able to find the object only by the value ('1' in the example), without having to specify the whole child document.

Is there any way to do it in Reactivemongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query by fields in an embedded or a nested document, use dot notation:

```
collection.find(BSONDocument("option.value" -> "1"))
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you!

Comment: Note that there is nothing specific to ReactiveMongo, there, the query engine is on server side

Comment: @cchantep Well said